# Why are pin definitions in Arduino declared static

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

In the Arduino codebase the definitions of the pins of the different compatible boards are stored in a file called pins_arduino.h, with a different version for each board.
The pin numbers are both declared and initialized in the header files for example:

```
static const uint8_t A0 = 14;
```

Two things surprised me about this: first that they would initialize a variable in the header - which I was taught not good practice. And second that they would declare them static, which in standard C++ would create a separate variable in each translation unit which included the file - seems like poor memory use in a memory restricted device.
Could anyone shed any light on why it was done like this and not, for example, declaring the pins extern in the header and then initializing them in a cpp file? Are there advantages to the declaration method used?

Thanks

James

Comment: This must be relying on a compiler-specific behavior, expecting the compiler to inline `static const` integral types.

Comment: You can get away with a lot of stuff that's stupid in the general case when you know exactly what your specific compiler will do.

Comment: I agree it is a bit weird. A better way would have been to declare them `inline constexpr uint8_t A0{14};`. But when I look at that (or a very similar) header file [here](https://github.com/wemos/Arduino_XI/blob/master/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h) I do see it predates C++11 (copyright 2007), and constexpr wasn't available then.

Comment: `static` is unnecessary in C++ (`const` implies `static` here) but C does not have the same rule, so I'm guessing it's for compatibility with C.

Answer (score 3):

> first that they would initialize a variable in the header - which I was taught not good practice.

Defining a variable in a header can break the One Definition Rule.  Declaring them as `static` resolves this.

> in standard C++ would create a separate variable in each translation unit which included the file - seems like poor memory use in a memory restricted device.

If the usage is inlined, no memory is used.  These variables would need to occupy memory if you took their addresses, but that would be an unusual usage of these variables.

> Could anyone shed any light on why it was done like this and not, for example, declaring the pins extern in the header and then initializing them in a cpp file?

If the variables were defined in a single cpp file, the compiler would have difficulty inlining the values in a different cpp file.